# Différences entre soir et nuit

Tags: sens, indications-de-temps

Les paroles de chanson :

> voulez vous coucher avec moi, ce soir?

sont-elles correctes? Pourquoi utilise-t-on « soir » et non « nuit » ?

Comment: In addition to all the accurate nuances pointed out by @Random between "soir" and "nuit", "soir" rhymes much better with "moi." If the lyrics had been in "Franglais", I bet they would have gotten away with using "nuit": "voulez vous coucher avec ME, cette nuit?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quand on parle de **cette nuit**, on fait référence au moment où l'on dort, donc on dirait plutôt des phrases comme

> As-tu bien dormi cette nuit ?

Alors que **ce soir** fait référence aux activités que l'on fait en fin de journée, avant d'aller dormir. Donc même si on parle d'une activité à 3h du matin, même si c'est une heure avancée dans la nuit, on va plutôt dire :

> J'ai regardé la télé jusqu'à 3h hier soir.

On peut cependant intentionnellement utiliser **cette nuit** pour insister sur le fait que la plupart des gens dorment, par exemple :

> J'ai regardé la télé toute la nuit *(sous-entendu : je n'ai pas dormi)*

ou encore :

> Les DJ travaillent de nuit

ou encore :

> J'ai vu un fantôme cette nuit

Comment: Merci @Gilles pour l'edit, je ne m'étais en effet pas relu...

Comment: Indépendamment de la question initiale, il me semble que le contraste peut aussi être interprété différemment. Soir décrit une période plus ou moins fixe de la journée quelle que soit la saison. Nuit décrit la période où le soleil est couché par opposition à jour. Il y a des soirs tous les jours, mais pas des nuits tous les soirs...